# Type command not working in Windows command prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the **type** command is supposed to display the contents of a text file in the Windows command prompt. But whenever I use the type command to display a text file, the output is only:

```
Unable to initialize device PRN
```

The command used is:

```
type C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Hello.txt
```

I don't know why it's doing this and I can't seem to figure it out. So if anyone could help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact command you are using?

Comment: are sure you are not using `print` command?

Comment: Yes I'm sure and I am using type C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Hello.txt

Comment: What is the output from `where type`?

Comment: What is the output from `mode`?

Comment: Which text encoding and in case of non Unicode which code page is used for the text file? See [How to fix a batch file with an Hebrew font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30478940/) for reason of the question. And `PRN` is the printer device and not the console which would be device `CON`. Output of `mode` would be really interesting (device other than `CON`) as well as output of `type /?` in case of there is an alias for `type`.

Comment: @MatthewMacGregor, would be interested to see what happens when you use redirection to force the output to the CONSOLE. `type C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Hello.txt >con` or even if it works redirecting to another file: `type C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Hello.txt >Hello2.txt`.  Does a FOR /F command read and output the file correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You echoed a 'print' command response to your file.

Open it with Notepad to verify.

Type is working (that's what's in the file).

Answer (score 0):

"Unable to initialize device PRN" is an odd error, you must be using an old version of Dos which is attempting to use a printer.

Which means you're either using the print command, or something you're trying to type is confusing the type command and returning an error.

```
set /p text=<type C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Hello.txt
echo "%text%" && pause
```