# Cyrillic characters are shown as abracadabra in Win cmd

Tags: windows, encoding, cmd, apache-kafka, cyrillic

When I dump out Kafka messages into Windows cmd with the following command:

```
kafka-console-consumer  --bootstrap-server example.server.net:31128 --topic MY_TOPIC_NAME --from-beginning
```

the Cyrillic characters are shown in the console as abracadabra.

I was following [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/625866/cmd-how-to-use-non-english-characters) to change my code page to UTF-8 with `chcp 65001`. Then I run cmd with `cmd /u` and set font to `Lucida Console`.

So if I write some Cyrillic characters into some txt file:

```
c:\test>echo привет > test.txt
```

the Cyrillic text is shown just fine. Then I dump out messages again but Cyrillic characters are still bad.

I was told that Kafka uses UTF-8 to store the data.

Could you please guide me how should I configure Win cmd to solve this issue?

Comment: Choose a font that supports Unicode.

Comment: CMD is just a shell. You're likely using the system console, so display results depend on the Windows version and configuration, such as the selected TrueType font. Exactly what command are you running to "dump out" text? CMD's internal `type` command?  more.com? These commands have to decode the input byte stream to Unicode since they use the console's wide-character API. We need to know the source encoding, and from there it depends on the command. `type` decodes using the console's output codepage. more.com decodes with the console's input codepage. chcp.com sets both.

Comment: I recommend reading [Using another language (code page) in a batch file made for others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48981387/) and [How to fix a batch file with an Hebrew font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30478940/) and [Why are Danish characters not displayed as in text editor on executing batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046559/) They are all about same problem: missing knowledge about [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).

Comment: @eryksun, I use external command to read Kafka messages. The source encoding is UTF-8

Comment: If the program naively writes bytes to the console, however they're encoded, via `WriteFile` or `WriteConsoleA`, then if those bytes happen to be UTF-8 encoded text, it should display properly if the console output codepage is set to 65001 and the selected font supports Cyrillic characters. (Depending on the program, in Windows 7 it might also write some garbage after each print, due to a bug in the Windows 7 console that causes it to misreport the number of bytes written.) However if the program makes assumptions such as transcoding UTF-8 to ANSI or OEM, the result will mojibake nonsense.

Comment: @DmitryStepanov Could you please show a screenshot with the issue?

Comment: @eryksun, you are right. The issue was that when I open command promt and check the code page it says it was 866 but not 65001. It looks like I have to change it every time from 866 to 56001 when I open a new console window.

Comment: Set a "CodePage" dword value of 65001 in a subkey of "HKCU\Console" that's named for the initial title of the console window, but with backslash replaced by underscore and the Windows directory replaced by "%SystemRoot%". By default, if the title isn't set explicitly, Windows uses the executable path as the title. For example, for cmd.exe the subkey is "HKCU\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe". This applies if we run CMD via the Win+R run dialog or `start cmd`, but *not* from a shortcut. (When entering the dword, make sure that decimal is selected in the dialog instead of hexadecimal.)

Comment: The codepage can be set in a shortcut, but I don't think the COM API to do so is documented, without which we'd have to modify the .LNK file directly. Maybe there's a library for that. Alternatively, in Windows 10 we can actually configure the ANSI and OEM system codepages as 65001 (UTF-8) in the administrative region settings in the control panel. The console defaults to OEM. (It would be nice if setting a "CodePage" default in "HKCU\Console" worked...)

Comment: @eryksun, yes, setting dword for `CodePage` in registry worked! Thanks a lot.

Comment: UTF-8 input via `ReadFile` or `ReadConsoleA` is still limited to 7-bit ASCII in all versions of Windows. UTF-8 uses 2-4 bytes per non-ASCII character, but the console assumes 1 byte per character. Thus, in Windows 7, a read that contains a non-ASCII character 'succeeds' with 0 bytes read. In Windows 10, a read of N characters will read N bytes, but non-ASCII characters are translated to null bytes. Given this, you might want to only set the "CodePage" value for a specific window title such as "UTF-8 Console", used like `start "UTF-8 Console"`.

Comment: Note that this UTF-8 bug doesn't affect Unicode (UTF-16) console clients such as CMD, PowerShell and Python 3.6+, which read input via the wide-character functions `ReadConsoleW` or `ReadConsoleInputW`. It only affects console clients that use `ReadFile`, `ReadConsoleA`, or `ReadConsoleInputA`, which depend on the console input codepage, i.e. which depend on the console translating its UTF-16 input buffer to a legacy codepage or UTF-8.