# Python-How to solve UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import urllib, urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment 
strg=""
iter=1
url='http://www.amazon.in/product-reviews/B00EOPJEYK/ref=cm_cr_pr_top_link_1?    ie=UTF8&pageNumber=1&showViewpoints=0&sortBy=bySubmissionDateDescending'
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
rows =soup.find_all('div',attrs={"class" : "reviewText"})
for row in soup.find_all('div',attrs={"class" : "reviewText"}):
      strg = strg +str(iter)+"." + row.text + "\n\n"
      iter=iter+1

with open('outp.txt','w') as f:
      f.write(strg)
f.close()
```

I require this code to write the contents of the variable,strg to the file,outp.txt.

Instead I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\demo_amazon.py", line 14, in <module>
f.write(strg)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2022' in position 226:   ordinal not in range(128)
```

strg stores the required output.There is some problem in the writing statement I guess.How to solve this?

Kindly help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, first of all, if you want to get rid of the unicode errors, you shall switch to Python 3 that defaults to unicode strings instead of ascii strings in python 2.

That said, to get rid of the `UnicodeEncodeError` exception, you shall do:

```
with open('outp.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(strg.encode('utf8'))
```

as a reference, see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048085/python-write-unicode-text-to-a-text-file). And try to use unicode strings as much as possible to avoid as much as possible changing charsets, by using `u"this is an unicode string"` instead of `"this is an ascii string"`

thus in your for loop:

```
  strg = strg +str(iter)+"." + row.text + "\n\n"
```

should instead be:

```
  strg = strg +unicode(iter)+u"." + row.text + u"\n\n"
```

and strg should be defined as `strg = u""`

N.B.: `f.close()` in your code is redundant with the use of the `with` keyword that actually takes care of closing the file when you exit the `with` block, through the `__exit__()` method of the `File` object.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have a non-ASCII character. I suggest using [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) which will try and find the "closest" ASCII character to the offending one. So, for instance it would turn é into e.

So you'd just do

```
from unidecode import unidecode
f.write(unidecode(strg))
```