# beautifulsoup - loop through url offset

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some tables from a website where there is about 100 pages, each page has an offset in the very end of the link, so my first link ends with offset=0, the next is offset=100, then offset=200, as you see it increase by 100.

With my code I can only get the output of the first page, could you guys help me how can I iterate through the offsets and outputting everything to the same file?

Python 2.7.5+ [GCC 4.8.1]

Beautifulsoup 3.2.1

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for x in range(500,800,100):
        numb = str(x)
        url = "http://www.mylink.com/blabla.offset="+numb
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

        with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
                for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:
                    tds = tr.find_all('td')
                    f.write( "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s$\n" % \
                          (tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text, tds[3].text, tds[4].text, tds[5].text, tds[6].text, tds[7].text, tds[8].text, tds[9].text, tds[10].text, tds[11].text, tds[12].text, tds[13].text, tds[14].text))
```

Comment: `range(500, 800, 100)` = `[500, 600, 700]`. If you mean to start at offset=0, you'll want `range(0, 800, 100)`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you could use `",".join(tds[i].text for i in range(15)) + '\n'` for `f.write`, instead of what you have here (or `",".join(td.text for td in tr.find_all('td'))` if there are 15 cells per row).

Comment: this is correct, but in the example above I get only the offset 500 while I need 500, 600, 700.

Comment: Each iteration over your `range` will overwrite `output.txt`. You may wish to use append mode (`open('out.txt', mode='a')`). Could that be your issue?

Comment: Spot on David! thank you very much! if you don't mind I add an extra question here. For some pages I'm getting the error ....      (tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text, tds[3].text, tds[4].text, tds[5].text, tds[6].text, tds[7].text, tds[8].text, tds[9].text, tds[10].text, tds[11].text, tds[12].text, tds[13].text, tds[14].text))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128) ... do you know what could that be?

Comment: Yes, you're trying to write Unicode strings (which all strings in BeautifulSoup are). Search around on the issue, or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048085/python-write-unicode-text-to-a-text-file for ways to solve this.

Comment: Thanks David, I looked up on that question but could not implement that solution to the write...

#Tried the following#

with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:
abc = tr.find_all('td')
for tds in abc:
tds.encode('utf8')
f.write("%s,..%s \n" % \
(tds[0].text...tds[14] ))

#Error message#

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./bomo.py", line 17, in <module>
(tds[0].text, tds[1].text...tds[14]))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2-py2.7.egg/bs4/element.py", line 905, in __getitem__
return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 0

Comment: just move the `with file` call to after your imports. this will create one file with all the input instead of overwriting it 3 times.

Comment: I can ignore some items it's not a problem, so I've done the following, problem resolved... (tds[0].text.encode('ascii','ignore'), tds[1].text.encode('ascii','ignore'),