# Error of conversion from Unicode to ASCII when writing a text file in Python

Tags: python, unicode

I am getting a plaintext from a webservice into an object `p` and I want to store it on a `.txt`file using Python.

I do something like:

```
with open("output","w") as t2:
    t2.write(p.content)
```

but the following encoding issue arises:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe8' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am on Ubuntu and PycharmIDE. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048085/python-write-unicode-text-to-a-text-file

Comment: documentation reference: [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/unicode.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using

`p2.content.encode('utf-8')`

or

`p2.content.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`

Comment: I think it worked and will accept your answer soon

Comment: What is the the output of `print p.content` and `print type(p.content)`?