# Failing to write output of HtmlDiff containing unicode text in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, difflib

I am trying to compare two Arabic strings using python's [`difflib.HtmlDiff`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#module-difflib) module. I have looked at various ways of writing the outputs of `HtmlDiff` to a file but none seems to work for me. Methods I have tried so far:

**Note:** in all subsequent code snippets, `original` and `mockinputs` are lists of strings, as required by [`HtmlDiff`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#module-difflib), of Unicode text, specifically Arabic.

`Method 1`

```
import difflib

hdiff = difflib.HtmlDiff()
html = hdiff.make_file(original, mockinputs)

with open('out_file.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out_file:
    out_file.write(html)
```

This runs without error but the html file created is gibberish (things like `Ø§Ù„Ø±Ø­Ù`) when opened in browser.

`Method 2` (as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048203/3375713))

```
import difflib

htmldiff = difflib.HtmlDiff()
html = htmldiff.make_file(original, mockinputs)

out_file = open('out_file.html', 'w')
out_file.write(html.encode('utf-8'))
out_file.close()
```

This gives me this error:

> TypeError: must be str, not bytes

So, how can I write Unicode texts produced by `HtmlDiff` as shown here to an html file in python 3?

I am using python 3.4.3.

Comment: This is a guess, but the documentation for `difflib` says that that the `make_file` method was changed for Python 3.5 to have a default charset of "utf-8": https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.HtmlDiff.make_file Did you try this in Python3.5? If I had to bet, I would look at that `make_file` method as the culprit. Also, your first two attempts are doing the same thing, and can you get `difflib` to work without creating an HTML table?

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that new change in 3.5. I think that's the ticket :-) But let's see what else turns up!

Comment: The documentation I linked above says that `make_file` used to have a default charset of `ISO-8859-1`, which would not include Arabic. Further, most browsers are going to see `ISO-8859-1` and fallback to ASCII (at least they used to). Thus, you have to use Python3.5 or generate the  output yourself. (Nevermind, you found it...)

Comment: With the first two methods, the HTML file might be valid UTF-8, but the browser may assume it is ISO-8859-1. You can try if inserting **<meta charset="UTF-8">** in the HTML header fixes the issue. Method 3 probably assumes you're using Python 2.

Comment: @roeland I mentioned in the title that I am using python 3, and meta charset thing is already there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.HtmlDiff.make_file), the `make_file` method in versions of Python before Python3.5 defaulted to a charset of ISO-8859-1, which would not include Arabic.

Further, most browsers are going to see ISO-8859-1 and fallback to ASCII. Thus, you have to use that method in Python3.5 in order to get **utf-8** or generate the HTML output that you would like in a different way.

**Edit:** as of python 3.5.1, though the `make_html` method uses default charset utf-8, its brother method `make_table` doesn't, so take care using the latter!