# How to convert text from TextArea to file?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-uploads

I have a `form` where `User` can fill either text to translate or attach a file. If the text to translate has been filled, I want to create a txt file from it so it seems like `User` uploaded a `txt` file.

```
    if job_creation_form.is_valid():
            cleaned_data_job_creation_form = job_creation_form.cleaned_data
            try:
                with transaction.atomic():
                        text = cleaned_data_job_creation_form.get('text_to_translate')
                        if text:
                           cleaned_data_job_creation_form['file']=create_txt_file(text)

                        Job.objects.create(
                                customer=request.user,
                                text_to_translate=cleaned_data_job_creation_form['text_to_translate'],
                                file=cleaned_data_job_creation_form['file']....
                                )
            except Exception as e:
                RaiseHttp404(request, 'Something went wrong :(')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('review_orders'))
```

I though about creating a `txt` file like:

```
with open('name.txt','a') as f:
    ...
```

But there can be many problems - the directory where the file is saved, the name of the file which uploading handles automatically etc.

Do you know a better way?

In short:

If the text to translate has been filled, fake it so it looks like `txt` file has been uploaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) maybe?

```
import tempfile
tmp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
tmp.write("Hello World!\n")
Job.objects.create(file=File(tmp),...)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, it works but there is an error when I pass characters like č,ú etc. It returns: Exception Value: 
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfa' in position 24: ordinal not in range(128). I tried to tmp.write(unicode(cleaned_data_job_creation_form.get('text_to_translate'))) But it's the same error.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048085/writing-unicode-text-to-a-text-file