# UnicodeEncodeError Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get the following error when try to write in file:

```
UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u'B\u1ea7u cua (B\u1ea7u cua 2017 )', 1, 2, 'ordinal not in range(128)'))
```

I try to write this text `Bầu cua` in file:

```
f = codecs.open("13.txt", "a", "utf-8")
f.write("{}\n".format(title))
```

Also I tried to use `title.encode()`

It gives me a new error:

When I use `.encode(text)` I get the following error: `

```
UnicodeDecodeError('ascii', 'B\xe1\xba\xa7u cua (B\xe1\xba\xa7u cua 2017 )\n', 1, 2, 'ordinal not in range(128)'))
`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing Unicode text to a text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048085/writing-unicode-text-to-a-text-file)

Comment: I have read this queastion also, and tried all advices

Comment: It does not work foe me `http://stackoverflow.com/a/6048203/7041624`

Comment: @MisterPi we can put encoding type at the start of file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37218065/1887976) to "Writing Unicode text to a text file?", you have many solutions.

Basically, you have 2 issues:

The `str.format()` method must be used on an `unicode` object

```
u'{}\n'.format('Bầu cua')
```

The file you write to also must be opened with the right encoding:

```
f = open('13.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
```

As a result, this works for Python 3:

```
data = 'Bầu cua'
f = open('13.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
line = u'{}\n'.format(data)
f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Comment: Yes, I applied your answer and now get error: `UnicodeDecodeError('ascii', 'Volkswagen Golf GTI \xe2\x80\x93 EBG\n', 20, 21, 'ordinal not in range(128)'))
`

Comment: Notice please attention on my comment

Answer (score 0):

Try with these two lines at the beginning of the file. It works well for Python2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

data = u'Bầu cua'
f = open('test.txt', 'a')
line = u'{}\n'.format(data)
f.write(line.encode('utf8'))
f.close()
```