# As a result of parsing(scraping), only English sentences are stored correctly

Tags: python, csv, parsing, twitter, web-scraping

As a result of parsing, only English sentences are stored correctly.

When you parse (scrape), you will come across other languages.

However, my code only stores English sentences correctly.

The emoticon is not saved either. (ex. ★♬◆♥)

How should I solve it?
Thank you for your advice.

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time

#Twitter Authentication Information
consumerKey = "x"
consumerSecret = "x"
accessToken = "x"
accessSecret = "x"

class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, tweetRaw):
        try:
            # Extract relevant information from the raw tweet data
            tweetAuthor = tweetRaw.split('"user":{"id":')[1].split(',"id_str":')[0]
            tweetText = tweetRaw.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source":')[0]
            tweetText = tweetText.replace(',', '')
            tweetDate = tweetRaw.split('"created_at":"')[1].split('","id":')[0]
            tweet = tweetDate + ',' + tweetAuthor + ',' + tweetText

            # Check tweet for location data
            try:
                tweetLocation = tweetRaw.split(',"geo":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[')[1] \
            .split(']},"coordinates":{"type":')[0]
                tweet = tweet + ',' + tweetLocation
            except:
            pass

        # Write tweet to file
        try:
            tweetToFile = open('rr.csv', 'a')
            tweetToFile.write(tweet)
            tweetToFile.write('\n')
            tweetToFile.close()
        except:
            print('Error! Unable to write to file.')
        return True

    except:
        time.sleep(5)

def on_error(self, status):
    print(status.tweetText)

auth = OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessSecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())

# Filter(s) for stream of tweets
## Geobox made using: http://boundingbox.klokantech.com/
indiaGeoBox = [[[139.5799775191,35.5341801276],[139.9369292191,35.5341801276],[139.9369292191,35.8307871111],[139.5799775191,35.8307871111],[139.5799775191,35.5341801276]]]
## Geobox contains tweets from parts of neighbouring countries

## Topic Filter
twitterStream.filter(track=['sing'or"day"])
twitterStream.filter(locations=indiaGeoBox)
```

indiaGeoBox = If not English speaking country(ex. korea.japan.china)

twitterStream.filter(track=['No English keyword'])

tweet : \ud83d\udcaf\ud83d\ude4f\ud83d\ udcaf\ud83d\ude4f\ud83d\udcaf\ud83d\ude4f

or

indiaGeoBox = If not English speaking country(ex. china.korea.japan)

twitterStream.filter(track=['English keyword'])

tweet : https://t.co/ppKCeiEU5n\n\ub178\ud1b5\uc758 \uc808\uce5c \ubb38\uc7ac\uc778

Comment: What exactly is your problem? 
To me it only looks as if you're receiving unicode and storing it as ascii.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048085/writing-unicode-text-to-a-text-file