# Printing unicode charcter in windows

Tags: python, windows, perl, unicode

I am trying to create file with Unicode character 662f on windows (via Perl or python, anything is fine for me ) . on Linux I am able to get chr 是 , but on windows I am getting this  character æ˜¯ , and some how I am not able to get that file name as 是.

**Python code** -

```
 import sys
 name = unichr(0x662f)
 print(name.encode('utf8').decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
```

**perl code -**

```
my $name .= chr(230).chr(152).chr(175); ##662f
print 'file name ::'. "$name"."txt";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing Unicode text to a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048085/writing-unicode-text-to-a-text-file)

Comment: Is the problem *printing* the file name, or *creating* a file with the desired name?

Comment: Problem is with creating a file with desired name .. just to check what file name is going through I am doing a print in sample code

Comment: For printing Unicode in Python 2, pip install and enable `win_unicode_console`. For creating a file with a non-ANSI name, use a `unicode` string for the name, e.g. `f = open(u'\u662f', 'w')`. To get a better experience with this in general, upgrade to Python 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

### File manipulation in Perl on Windows (Unicode characters in file name)

In Perl on Windows, I use `Win32::Unicode`, `Win32::Unicode::File` and `Win32::Unicode::Dir`. They work perfectly with Unicode characters in file names.

Just mind that `Win32::Unicode::File::open()` (and `new()`) have a reversed argument order compared Perl's built-in `open()` - mode comes first.

You do not need to encode the characters manually - just insert them as they are (if your Perl script is in UTF-8), or using the `\x{N}` notation.

---

### Printing out Unicode characters on Windows

Printing Unicode into console on Windows is another problem. You can't use `cmd.exe`. Instead use PowerShell ISE. The drawback of the ISE is that it's not a console - scripts can't take input from keyboard thru `STDIN`.

To get Unicode output, you need to do set the output encoding to UTF-8 in every PowerShell ISE that's started. I suggest doing so in the startup script.

#### Procedure to have PowerShell ISE default to Unicode output:

1) In order for any user PowerShell scripts to be allowed to run, you first need to do:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

2) Edit or create your `Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1` to something like:

```
perl -w -e "print qq!Initializing the console with Perl...\n!;"
[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8;
```

The short Perl command is there as a trick to allow the `System.Console` property be modified. Without it, you get an error when setting the `OutputEncoding`.

If I recall correctly, you also have to change the font to Consolas.

Even when the Unicode characters print out fine, you may have trouble including them in command line arguments. In these cases I've found the `\x{N}` notation works. The Windows Character Map utility is your friend here.

---

(Edited heavily after I rediscovered the regular PowerShell's inability to display most Unicode characters, with references to PowerShell (non-ISE) removed. Now I remember why I started using the ISE...)