# python writing text data to text file

Tags: python, file

I have this piece of code in python:

```
def write_to_log_file(text):
    with open ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\log.txt",mode='w') as file:
        file.write(text)
```

however when I run this code I am getting the following error:

```
line 13, in write_to_log_file
    file.write(text)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 126: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Try to encode your unicode string as ascii:`unicodeData.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`

Comment: Please show some of the text that you are trying to write. Especially, what format the text is in right now. I expect that your text is unicode and as such needs to be treated differently.

Comment: Please check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) on the `open` function and, considering the error message you got, make an educated guess about which additional parameter you need to pass to `open`.

Comment: @BasJansen - this is the code I am using:
text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.pe-wp-default:nth-child(2) > p:nth-child(1)").text
        print text
and when I print it to the console this is the text I am getting:
We understand that every organization has unique critical data characteristics, so manual policies are not sufficient in today’s world. Through advanced machine learning technologies, we automatically classify sensitive data, enforce data security policy and demonstrate compliance.

Comment: We understand that every organization has unique critical data characteristics, so manual policies are not sufficient in today’s world. Through advanced machine learning technologies, we automatically classify sensitive data, enforce data security policy and demonstrate compliance.

Comment: @Mandy8055, observe: `'नमस्ते'.encode('ascii', 'ignore') == b""`

Comment: Sorry Sir(@ForceBru) I didn't get that what are you trying to depictt?

Comment: @ErezN Look at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm and see if you understand why this is failing. Tip: Think about ASCII versus unicode.

Comment: @Mandy8055, this is effectively destroying all non-Unicode data.

Comment: Okay Sir(@ForceBru).Thanks

Comment: Please check the answer to this similar question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048085/writing-unicode-text-to-a-text-file)

```
def write_to_log_file(text):
    with open ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\log.txt",mode='w') as file:
        file.write(text.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem!

Comment: Or just `open("file", "w", encoding="UTF8")`.

Comment: @ErezN I'm glad I helped you. Please mark this answer as an accepted one.