# Python scraping encoding issues

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, web-scraping, decoding

I am attempting to scrape a website using beautifulsoup. I am largely successful but having two issues

1. After I get the data from website I am printing them to the screen as well as 
   writing them into a CSV file. There is a price field in the website which has 
   a rupee symbol in from of the actual amount (sample structure of the price 
   field :₹ 10000). When I print the amount to console, it prints well and there 
   are no issues. When I try to write it to the excel sheet, I get the error 
   "Unicodeencoeerror" codec 'charmap' cannot encode character '\u20b9' in 
   position 28. I am printing other fields to console and excel the issue shows 
   up only with two fields one with the currency symbol and other with a * 
   symbol
2. I have a loop running to get all pages from the webpage for a particular 
   search. The search result is about 344 pages but the loop stops at about page 
   43 with only HTML error 500 as the error message

   ```
   import bs4
   from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
   filename = "data.csv"
   f = open(filename,"w")
   headers = "phone_name, phone_price, phone_rating,number_of_ratings, 
   memory, display, camera, battery, processor, Warrenty, security, OS\n"
   f.write(headers)


   for i in range(2):      # Number of pages minus one 
           my_url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/search?as=off&as-
           show=on&otracker=start&page=
           {}&q=cell+phones&viewType=list'.format(i+1)
           print(my_url)

           uClient=uReq(my_url)

           page_html=uClient.read()

           page_soup = Soup(page_html,"html.parser")

           containers=page_soup.findAll("a", {"class":"_1UoZlX"})




   for container in containers:          phone_name        =  
   container.find("div",{"class":"_3wU53n"}).text

      try:
      phone_price =  container.find("div",{"class":"_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK"}).text

      except:
      phone_price           =  'No Data'
   ```

Thanks you very much for all you help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is important to post relevant code if you need help with debugging something together with it's expected behavior. Code can help for question 1. For the second, clearly you are scraping too fast and the server starts to throttle you down by throwing that error. Try adding a delay of some seconds after every page.

Comment: Thanks..added the code

Comment: If you are using Python 2.6-2.7 you probably need [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html) which allows to specify the encoding (in this case unicode): https://stackoverflow.com/a/35086151/2464424

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When writing .CSV files for Excel, the `utf-8-sig` encoding should be used to support any Unicode character correctly.  Excel will assume the localized ANSI encoding on Windows if just `utf8` is used and display characters incorrectly.

```
#!python3
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

filename = "data.csv"
with open(filename,'w',newline='',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    headers = 'phone_name phone_price phone_rating number_of_ratings memory display camera battery processor Warrenty security OS'
    w.writerow(headers.split())

    for i in range(2):      # Number of pages minus one 
            my_url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/search?as=off&as-show=on&otracker=start&page={}&q=cell+phones&viewType=list'.format(i+1)
            print(my_url)
            uClient=uReq(my_url)
            page_html=uClient.read()
            page_soup = Soup(page_html,"html.parser")
            containers=page_soup.findAll("a", {"class":"_1UoZlX"})

    for container in containers:
        phone_name = container.find("div",{"class":"_3wU53n"}).text

        try:
            phone_price = container.find("div",{"class":"_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK"}).text
        except:
            phone_price = 'No Data'

        w.writerow([phone_name,phone_price])
```

Output:

```
phone_name,phone_price,phone_rating,number_of_ratings,memory,display,camera,battery,processor,Warrenty,security,OS
"Asus Zenfone 3 Laser (Gold, 32 GB)","₹9,999"
"Intex Aqua Style III (Champagne/Champ, 16 GB)","₹3,999"
"iVooMi i1s (Platinum Gold, 32 GB)","₹7,499"
"Xolo ERA 3X (Posh Black, 16 GB)","₹6,999"
"iVooMi Me1 (Sunshine Gold, 8 GB)","₹3,599"
"Panasonic Eluga A4 (Mocha Gold, 32 GB)","₹9,790"
Samsung Metro 313 Dual Sim,"₹2,025"
"Samsung Galaxy J3 Pro (Gold, 16 GB)","₹6,990"
Samsung Guru Music 2,"₹1,625"
"Panasonic Eluga A4 (Marine Blue, 32 GB)","₹9,640"
"Asus Zenfone 4 Selfie (Black, 32 GB)","₹9,999"
Swipe Elite 3- 4G with VoLTE,"₹3,999"
"Asus Zenfone Max (Black, 16 GB)","₹7,486"
Swipe Elite 3- 4G with VoLTE,"₹3,999"
"Swipe Elite Power (Space Grey, 16 GB)","₹5,499"
"Celkon Diamond Mega (Grey, 16 GB)","₹5,499"
"Asus Zenfone Max (Black, 32 GB)","₹7,999"
"Swipe Elite Power (Champagne Gold, 16 GB)","₹5,499"
"Asus Zenfone 4 Selfie (Gold, 32 GB)","₹9,999"
"Karbonn Aura (Champagne, 8 GB)","₹3,199"
"Infinix Note 4 (Ice Blue, 32 GB)","₹8,999"
"Infinix Note 4 (Milan Black, 32 GB)","₹8,999"
"Moto G5s Plus (Blush Gold, 64 GB)","₹15,990"
"Moto G5s Plus (Lunar Grey, 64 GB)","₹15,940"
```

Excel:

[image]