# python: writing ★ in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to use:

```
text = "★"
file.write(text)
```

In python 3. But I get this error message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I print the symbol ★ in a file in python? This is the same symbol that is being used as star ratings.

Comment: You'll want to use a different encoding. `with open('file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f: f.write("★")`

Comment: As long as Python lives, these pesky questions around Unicode will keep coming. I don't understand Python didn't get it right, even in v3.

Comment: @nehemiah I agree, I wish this was automatic in python so the programmer didn't need to take care of these details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing Unicode text to a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048085/writing-unicode-text-to-a-text-file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default `open` uses the platform default encoding (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open)):

> encoding is the name of the encoding used to decode or encode the file. This should only be used in text mode. The default encoding is platform dependent (whatever `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns), but any text encoding supported by Python can be used. See the `codecs` module for the list of supported encodings.

This might not be an encoding that supports not-ascii characters as you noticed yourself. If you know that you want utf-8 then it's always a good idea to provide it explicitly:

```
with open(filename, encoding='utf-8', mode='w') as file:
    file.write(text)
```

Using the `with` context manager also makes sure there is no file handle around in case you forget to close or it throws an exception before you close the handle.