# 'ascii' codec can't encode character when redirecting Python script to file through Bash

Tags: python, unicode

I have the following script (test.py), printin a non-ASCII character:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print u"café"
```

It works as expected when running at shell:

```
$ python test.py 
café
```

However, if I try the usual bash redirect with `>` it fails in the following way:

```
$ python test.py > result.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    print u"café"
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How this can be solved?

Python version, in the case it helps:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.6.6
```

**EDIT1**: note this question is not a duplicated of [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048085/writing-unicode-text-to-a-text-file). In the referred question they are using file abstraction in Python, e.g. `open()`, etc. while in my question these abstractions are not used and I'm using bash redirection.

**EDIT2**: check bash unicode support, as suggested in comments:

```
$ bash --version | head -n 1
GNU bash, versión 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 35; columns 150; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts -cdtrdsr
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
$ echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac'
€
```

Comment: Your script (.py) file use the UTF-8 codepage ? Not ANSI or another codepage ? You need UTF-8 codepage for your python script file.

Comment: @William_Wilson I don't think is a duplicated. In the referred question they are using file abstraction in Python, e.g. open(), etc. while in my question these abstractions are not used and I'm using bash redirection.

Comment: @s3n0 I have run `file test.py` and I get `test.py: UTF-8 Unicode text`. Not sure if you refer to that with "UTF-8 codepage". Otherwise, please tell me how to get the codepage and I'll provide the result.

Comment: What about `bash --version` and terminal `stty -a` ? Is there a utf-8 support ? Try `echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac'`, when your terminal support utf-8, then you will see the result: `€`.

Comment: @s3n0 question post edited to included the detail you request. Check was ok.

Comment: Here's the explanation for the problem - https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html#frustration-3-inconsistent-treatment-of-output - with your `print u'café'` example too :). Did you find it here ? and can not you read it ? or do you just need to explain it better ? OMG ? :)

Comment: I use Python 2.7.13 and I do not have these problems. All the similar problems that can be found on the Internet, point to a problem with Python 2.6.x. Can you try a new version of Python 2.7.x (if possible)? UTF-8 support in Bash and Terminal are OK. So the problem will be apparent in Python - when converting Unicode to String (byte) when writing data to a text file. Unfortunately, if you do not have Python 2.7, you have to solve the problem with a more complex code entry, as shown on the web site above.

Comment: @s3n0 "café" was a random word I chose for the example, in Spanish but international enough to not sound too weird for English speakers. Probably the author of that article had a similar idea to chose the example. Funny :D