# Why isn't Python writing characters from Latin Extended-A (UnicodeEncodeError when writing to a file)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, codec

**Obligatory intro noting that I've done some research**

This seems like it should be straightforward (I am happy to close as a duplicate if a suitable target question is found), but I'm not familiar enough with character encodings and how Python handles them to suss it out myself. At risk of seeming lazy, I will note the answer very well may be in one of the links below, but I haven't yet seen it in my reading.

I've referenced some of the docs: [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html), [codecs.py docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

I've also looked at some old highly-voted SO questions: [Writing Unicode text to a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048085/writing-unicode-text-to-a-text-file), [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console)

---

**Question**

Here's a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code example that demonstrates my problem:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'wt') as outfile:
    outfile.write('\u014d')
```

The traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\cashamerica\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u014d' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

I'm confused because the code point `U+014D` is 'ō', an assigned code point, `LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH MACRON` ([official Unicode source](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0100.pdf))

I can even print the the character to the Windows console (but it renders as a normal 'o'):

```
>>> print('\u014d')
o
```

Comment: You're trying to encode it to CP1252, in which this letter doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `cp1252` as the default encoding, which does not include `ō`.

Write (and read) your file with explicit encoding:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'wt', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    outfile.write('\u014d')
```

Comment: I did not realize `open` encoded to `cp1252`; that's really kind of a rough edge. I guess I should have read the [docs for `open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), which state: "In text mode, if *encoding* is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent: `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is called to get the current locale encoding."