# Writelines is not reading special characters - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm developing a cod to automate tables. I'm still at the beginning of what I want to do. Anyway, the cod it creates has to be played in a text file. However, some special characters it cannot read

Ex: ...value='S�O PAULO (CGH)';...

```
try:
    file = open('codigo.txt', 'w')
    file.writelines(cod)
except FileNotFoundError:
    file = open('codigo.txt', 'w')
    file.writelines(cod)
file.close()
```

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: It's an encoding problem.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why I'm asking for help because I don't know what to do.

Comment: How are you setting `cod`?

Comment: Why does your `except` block run the same code as `try`? If it got an error the first time, it will get the same error.

Comment: cod is a string. It's a variable with the entire script.

Comment: And opening for writing won't get `FileNotFoundError`, it creates the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you try  `file.write(string.encode('utf8'))`?

Comment: This shouldn't happen with a string, are you sure it's not a byte string?

Comment: About the except, I forgot to take

Comment: Same question was here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048085/writing-unicode-text-to-a-text-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try
`file = open('file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')`
(or a different encoding)

For more, see - https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

Comment: GREAT. I hadn't thought about it hahaha. Vlw brother!