# Save HTML Source Code to File

Tags: python-3.x

How can I copy the source code of a website into a text file in Python 3?

EDIT:
To clarify my issue, here's what I have:

```
import urllib.request

def extractHTML(url):
    f = open('temphtml.txt', 'w')
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    pagetext = page.read()
    f.write(pagetext)
    f.close()

extractHTML('http:www.google.com')
```

I get the following error for the f.write() function:

```
builtins.TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: Have you tried looking here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512811/builtins-typeerror-must-be-str-not-bytes

Comment: Surprisingly, none of the answers (except one) actually addressed the issue.. `pagetext` is NOT a string.. It's actually bytes. So to convert it to a string, you need to use `f.write(pagetext.decode('utf-8'))` which will a UTF-8 encoded string to the file.

Comment: @Brandon  I tried what you said and got an error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 8482: invalid start byte`.  I just literally copied down my answer without the `str()` and put  `f.write(pagetext.decode('utf-8'))` in the place of `f.write(pagetext)`. Any idea why this is not working for me.  If you are using Python 2 that might be why

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save HTML of some website in a txt file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297257/save-html-of-some-website-in-a-txt-file-with-python)

Answer (score 3):

```
import urllib.request
site = urllib.request.urlopen('http://somesite.com')
data = site.read()
file = open("file.txt","wb") #open file in binary mode
file.writelines(data)
file.close()
```

Untested but should work.

EDIT: Updated for python3

Comment: Oops, sorry. What's the issue in python 3?

Comment: urllib2 doesn't exist, for starters.  I think typically you'd use the urllib.request module (that's where urlopen now lives.)

Comment: Oops, seems this is redundant now that OP has updated their post.

Comment: I think you will have the same str/bytes problem. The HTTP response has bytes, but you've opened the file for writing str. The simplest way is just to open the file in binary mode (with `"wb"`).

Comment: Yes, this was posted before OP added what their problem was.

Comment: This works fine, thanks. Is there a way to store the source code as lines of strings?

Comment: I mean as opposed to an array of bytes (writing in binary mode), simply writing them to a file as a string.

Comment: Using wb gives me this error for http://notalwaysright.com/page/1: `TypeError: 'int' does not support the buffer interface`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import urllib.request
def extractHTML(url):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'temphtml.txt')
```

---

It is easier, but if you still want to do it that way.  This is the solution:

```
import urllib.request

def extractHTML(url):
    f = open('temphtml.txt', 'w')
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    pagetext = str(page.read())
    f.write(pagetext)
    f.close()

extractHTML('https://www.google.com')
```

Your script gave an error saying it must be a string.  Just convert bytes to a string with `str()`.

Next I got an error saying no host was given.  [Google is a secured site so `https:` not `http:`](https://www.instantssl.com/https-tutorials/what-is-https.html) and most importantly you forgot to include [`//`](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071123125213AAhfij8) at the end of `https:`.

Answer (score 0):

> probably you wanted to create something like that:

```
import urllib.request

class ExtractHtml():

    def Page(self):

        print("enter the web page name starting with 'http://': ")
        url=input()
        site=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        data=site.read()
        file =open("D://python_projects/output.txt", "wb")
        file.write(data)
        file.close()






w=ExtractHtml()
w.Page()
```