# Save HTML of some website in a txt file with python

Tags: python, html, parsing, python-3.x, urllib

I need save the HTML code of any website in a txt file, is a very easy exercise but I have doubts with this because a have a function that do this:

```
import urllib.request

def get_html(url):
    f=open('htmlcode.txt','w')
    page=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    pagetext=page.read() ## Save the html and later save in the file
    f.write(pagetext)
    f.close()
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: You can ask your browser to save the HTML for a page. Why do it this way? There are programs like `wget` (on Unix/Linux, probably also on OSX, and also on Windows as part of CygWin) that can download a complete website.

Comment: Lots of programmers use python to download urls. I do. I guess I could hire a bunch of people to click save from the browser. I could send them email telling them which pages I want. But python is less expensive.

Comment: I had a strange error, say something like: "No str, needed bytes"

Comment: Great! The problem is that you need to convert the buffer to a string form. Pagetext=page.read().decode() is probably all you need. This gives you UTF8.

Comment: Yes, your right! Finally I get it, thanks for all :D

Comment: Don't put answers in the question.

Comment: I applied all what you all said using that code but i'm still getting an error saying `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2665' in position` :'(

Comment: @MohammedAminAIMEUR Hello, have you tried this one? import urllib2 def get_html(url): file("my_file.txt", "w").write(urllib2.urlopen(url).read()) if name == 'main': url=raw_input("Say me a website: ") get_htmll("http://"+url)

Comment: well I've found a solution to it, i'm using python3 and the code i used is the following: `page = urllib.request.urlopen(url1)
    f = open("./offlinesaved.html", "wb")
    shutil.copyfileobj(page, f)
    f.close()`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use [urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve):

```
import urllib

urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.example.com/test.html", "test.txt")
```

For Python 3.x the code is as follows:

```
import urllib.request    
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.example.com/test.html", "test.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks! I have done the next way, and working: import urllib2


def Obtener_Html(url):
 file("my_file.txt", "w").write(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())


if __name__ == '__main__':
 url=raw_input("Say me a website: ")
 Obtener_Html("http://"+url)

Answer (score 10):

I use `Python 3`.
`pip install requests` - after install `requests` library you can save a webpage in txt file.

```py
import requests

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297257/save-html-of-some-website-in-a-txt-file-with-python"

r = requests.get(url)
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(r.text)
```

Comment: Might want to also check status_code to make sure that you are not running into http 404 or some server error. It should be http 200, ok=true