# How can I save source code from a website in a .txt file?

Tags: python-3.x

```
url = "http://" + str(input)
t = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

how can I save the sourcecode of any Website in an .txt file?
I use python version 3

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968091/save-html-source-code-to-file

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways you can get this done.

### step 1: getting the data

This can be done using any library of your choice, My personal favorite is requests, the code goes as follows

```
import requests
headers = {'User-agents':'Mozilla/5.0'}
html_data = requests.get('Your url goes here',headers=headers)
```

This code will store the object at a location, to get the data in text format you can use

```
html_data = html_data.text
```

### Step 2: Saving this data into a text file on the local machine

```
file = open('your file path goes here','ab') //this will open the file you have specified in the path
file.write(html.text.encode('UTF-8')) //Most of the HTML pages are encoded in ascii, you need to convert it into 'UTF-8' encoding to write it into a txt file.
file.close() //Close the file. all the mishaps in the world will happen if you don't close the file which is opened
```

This will save all the html code from a website to the text file which you have mentioned in the path.

If you were explicitly referring to saving the visible data in the website, try using some parser library, I Recommend using BeautifulSoup.

Here are the links to the actual python documentations for the libraries used and recommended.

- Lib - Requests - [link to the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)
- Lib - BeautifulSoup - [Link to the Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of videos and tutorials about this, but still:

```
import urllib

t = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

with open("c:\\source_code.txt",'w') as source_code:
    source_code.write(t)
```

Comment: It shows error: must be str, not bytes. Dont know what it means.

Answer (score 0):

This is the quickest way:

```
import urllib.request
a = str(input())
url = "http://" + a
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'page.txt')
```

Bear in mind the site may not always be `http://` and `input()` always takes `()`