# How to save web page's source

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello i want save web page's source codes to any any text file and saving it C:\ folder.

I tried get web page's source with this code:

```
html = driver.page_source
print(html)
```

How to save page source to C:\ folder in a text file?

Comment: `open("C:\\file.txt", "w+").write(html)`

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE Hello im getting this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u226b' in position 1943721: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18367068/15578194)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import urllib.request
site = urllib.request.urlopen('http://somesite.com')
data = site.read()
file = open("C:\\file.txt","wb") #open file in binary mode
file.writelines(data)
file.close()
```

or this

```py
import urllib.request
def extractHTML(url):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'C:\\file.txt')
```

See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9968091/3485434)

Comment: Hello i need do this in selenium

Comment: You can do this as written in my answer and do all the rest with selenium.

Comment: Hello, i did transfer your code but im getting this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'. How do i combine this with my code?

Comment: Are you sure you did this: `import urllib.request
site = urllib.request.urlopen('http://somesite.com')` and not this: `html = driver.page_source` before applying `read()` method on it?

Comment: Hello, yes i restored code but im getting this error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'. Is there any way to do this without using urllib? Because im using my cookies and histories in webdriver.