# EOFError Python 2.7 to 3 migration

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pickle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [builtins.TypeError: must be str, not bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512811/builtins-typeerror-must-be-str-not-bytes)

I wrote a program to write a dict to file and in Python 2.7 it works well, but now in Python 3 I receive `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface` and `TypeError: must be str, not bytes`

**CODE UPDATED**

**Inputs**: path to dir, file name (`!hamers.txt` for example) and new dictionary

**Outputs**: none

**Effects**: Generate new file with dictionary. Check if file exists and then merge two dictionaries (existing and new).

```
def generate_file_from_dict(self, path, fname, my_new_dict):                   
                    mfile = self.add_slash(path)+fname
            if os.path.exists(mfile):
                    mfile = open(mfile, 'rb')
                    my_existing_dict = pickle.load(mfile)
                    my_new_dict = dict(my_existing_dict.items() + my_new_dict.items())
                    mfile.close()
            mfile = open(self.add_slash(path)+fname, 'wb+')
            pickle.dump(my_new_dict, mfile)
            mfile.close()
```

**Now its**

```
my_existing_dict = pickle.load(mfile)
EOFError
```

Comment: I'm always puzzled by this sort of question, doesn't the error tell you what exactly the problem is? It says `"must be a str, not bytes"`. How else could this be interpreted but to mean, that you're trying to pass `bytes`, when you should pass `str`.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe I ask because on Python 2.7 it works fine!?

Comment: May be you should read docs?

Comment: @VladislavIl'ushin: When switching a major version of anything, you should expect that not everything works. This might help you: http://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file should opened in binary

```
mfile = open(mfile,'rb')

mfile = open(self.add_slash(path)+fname, 'wb+')
```

Comment: `my_existing_dict = pickle.load(mfile)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

Comment: @VladislavIl'ushin: all `open` calls should use `b` mode, when using pickle. **all** calls.

Comment: OK, a edit it, but now `my_existing_dict = pickle.load(mfile)
EOFError`, where mfile is `mfile = open(mfile, 'wb+')`

Comment: @VladislavIl'ushin: read the answer. People are actually trying to help you. Is this what Pearsonartphoto suggested you do?

Comment: Look at my updated  code, look at answer, at my code, at answer. Of course I do `'wb+'` thing.

Comment: @VladislavIl'ushin: I have and that's why I'm telling you to read the answer again. Why on earth you're _`'wb+' thing_ I have no idea.