# Python 3 TypeError: must be str, not bytes with sys.stdout.write()

Tags: python

I was looking for a way to run an external process from python script and print its stdout messages during the execution.
The code below works, but prints no stdout output during runtime. When it exits I am getting the following error:

> sys.stdout.write(nextline) TypeError:must be str,not bytes

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["demo.exe"],stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.PIPE)    
# Poll process for new output until finished
while True:
    nextline = p.stdout.readline()
    if nextline == '' and p.poll() != None:
        break
    sys.stdout.write(nextline)
    sys.stdout.flush()

output = p.communicate()[0]
exitCode = p.returncode
```

I am using python 3.3.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [builtins.TypeError: must be str, not bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512811/builtins-typeerror-must-be-str-not-bytes)

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Python 3 handles strings a bit different. Originally there was just one type for
strings: `str`. When unicode gained traction in the '90s the new `unicode` type
was added to handle Unicode without breaking pre-existing code<sup>1</sup>. This is
effectively the same as `str` but with multibyte support.

In Python 3 there are two different types:

- The `bytes` type. This is just a sequence of bytes, Python doesn't know
  anything about how to interpret this as characters.
- The `str` type. This is also a sequence of bytes, *but Python knows how to
  interpret those bytes as characters*.
- The separate `unicode` type was dropped. `str` now supports unicode.

In Python 2 implicitly assuming an encoding could cause a lot of problems; you
could end up using the wrong encoding, or the data may not have an encoding at
all (e.g. it’s a PNG image).
Explicitly telling Python which encoding to use (or explicitly telling it to
guess) is often a lot better and much more in line with the "Python philosophy"
of "[explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)".

This change is incompatible with Python 2 as many return values have changed,
leading to subtle problems like this one; it's probably the main reason why
Python 3 adoption has been so slow. Since Python doesn't have static typing<sup>2</sup>
it's impossible to change this automatically with a script (such as the bundled
`2to3`).

- You can convert `str` to `bytes` with `bytes('h€llo', 'utf-8')`; this should
  produce `b'H\xe2\x82\xacllo'`. Note how one character was converted to three
  bytes.
- You can convert `bytes` to `str` with  `b'H\xe2\x82\xacllo'.decode('utf-8')`.

Of course, UTF-8 may not be the correct character set in your case, so be sure
to use the correct one.

In your specific piece of code, `nextline` is of type `bytes`, not `str`,
reading `stdout` and `stdin` from `subprocess` changed in Python 3 from `str` to
`bytes`. This is because Python can't be sure which encoding this uses. It
*probably* uses the same as `sys.stdin.encoding` (the encoding of your system),
but it can't be sure.

You need to replace:

```
sys.stdout.write(nextline)
```

with:

```
sys.stdout.write(nextline.decode('utf-8'))
```

or maybe:

```
sys.stdout.write(nextline.decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
```

You will also need to modify `if nextline == ''` to `if nextline == b''` since:

```
>>> '' == b''
False
```

Also see the [Python 3 ChangeLog](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit), [PEP 358](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0358/), and [PEP 3112](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3112/).

---

<sup>1</sup> There are some neat tricks you can do with ASCII that you can't do with multibyte character sets; the most famous example is the "xor with space to switch case" (e.g. `chr(ord('a') ^ ord(' ')) == 'A'`) and "set 6th bit to make a control character" (e.g. `ord('\t') + ord('@') == ord('I')`). ASCII was designed in a time when manipulating individual bits was an operation with a non-negligible performance impact.

<sup>2</sup> Yes, you can use function annotations, but it's a comparatively new feature and little used.

Comment: +1 for the tip!Btw I see I am getting the stdout only at the end of the program.Can you tell me why it doesn't print in real time?

Comment: Without knowing what `demo.exe` outputs, and what *exactly* you want, It's difficult to answer your question, since it's not clear what the question is :-) Be aware though, that `readline()` reads a *line*, that is, it keeps reading until it encounters a newline, which, on Windows, I believe, is `\r\n` and not `\n`

Comment: What I am trying to do is to print demo.exe stdout messages while it is running in python.Currently python prints demo.exe stdout only at the subprocess termination

Comment: @MichaelIV don't know why you don't have any output. I tested it and it works for me. I also tested it on Windows to be sure. Make sure that `demo.exe` outputs `\r\n` line-endings, and that `demo.exe` is also flushing stdout.

Answer (score 36):

While the accepted answer will work fine if the bytes you have from your subprocess are encoded using `sys.stdout.encoding` (or a compatible encoding, like reading from a tool that outputs ASCII and your stdout uses UTF-8), the correct way to write arbitrary bytes to stdout is:

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write(some_bytes_object)
```

This will just output the bytes as-is, without trying to treat them as text-in-some-encoding.

Comment: As part of a migration, I would accept this answer as the correct one. For example i can not change how csv module write its data. So in my opinion the best way to go is just pass data as is to stdout. Thanks for this piece!

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for :D