# Reverse engineering python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if there is a way to get around this error. Any help would be appreciated!

```
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

```
import marshal, imp

f=open('PYTHONSCRIPT','rb')
f.seek(28)  # Skip the header, you have to know the header size beforehand

ob=marshal.load(f)

for i in range(0,len(ob)):
    open(str(i)+'.pyc','wb').write(imp.get_magic() + '\0'*4 + marshal.dumps(ob[i]))

f.close()

open(str(i)+'.pyc','wb').write(imp.get_magic() + '\0'*4 + marshal.dumps(ob[i]))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 TypeError: must be str, not bytes with sys.stdout.write()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689365/python-3-typeerror-must-be-str-not-bytes-with-sys-stdout-write)

Comment: please provide the full stack trace.

Comment: The `str` and `bytes` types are not compatible. You must convert one of them. The above answer should give you the information and details you need.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker not even that, need to have something with `str` + `bytes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to concatenate two `byte`s and a `str`. This is not possible in python3 because python3 makes a clear distinction between bytes and strings (a good thing given the somewhat fuzzy distinctions between `str` and `unicode` in python2). I think what you want is probably the following:

```
import marshal, imp

f=open('PYTHONSCRIPT','rb')
f.seek(28)  # Skip the header, you have to know the header size beforehand

ob=marshal.load(f)

for i in range(0,len(ob)):
    with open(str(i)+'.pyc','wb') as my_file:
        my_file.write(imp.get_magic() + b'\0'*4 + marshal.dumps(ob[i]))

f.close()

with open(str(i)+'.pyc','wb') as my_file:
    my_file.write(imp.get_magic() + b'\0'*4 + marshal.dumps(ob[i]))
```

The `b` before the strings is a marker that tells python that the strings are `byte` strings instead of `str` strings.

Note also that I added `with ... as ...:` which will make sure that your files get deterministically closed right away even in non-CPython implementations (PyPy, Jython, IronPython, etc).

Comment: Good general advice for `with` but this code pretty certainly does  not run on anything else besides CPython :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I don't follow. It looks like pretty standard python that would at least run on pypy (I can't speak for Jython or IronPython as I don't know them well enough). Do you know something about the questioner's application that I do not?

Comment: it messes with CPython .pyc files, certainly wouldn't work on Jython which uses java .classes. At least Jython 2.7 seems to have `imp.get_magic` that returns the CPython get_magic, but marshal is not compatible.

Comment: Ah, marshal on jython can't marshal functions/code objects, so this definitely cannot run at all.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I'm pretty sure that functions/code objects aren't marshal-able even by CPython.

Comment: You're very wrong there. The `.pyc` files are `marshal`led module contents.

Answer (score 2):

`'\0'*4` is a `str`, use `b'\0' * 4` to get the needed `bytes` value.