# How to get input of password, but replacing characters with '*'

Tags: python, python-3.x

All in the title really...

I know you can use

```
getpass.getpass()
```

however, if distributing some code like this, people are used to having their characters by '*' so could give the impression that may make them believe their keyboard isn't working when they see no characters popping up on the screen.

I want to have `'example'` show up as `'*******'` during the input, so that:

```
Enter Password: example
```

will show up as

```
Enter Password: *******
```

Thanks for any answers

Comment: You can change the prompt from getpass, e.g. getpass.getpass(prompt='Enter password (NB you receive no indication that a character was entered from e.g. an asterisk):')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a work around for you, which you can modify to your needs:

1. Install [getch](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/getch): `pip install getch`. This module has methods for getting input char by char.
2. Create a function that gets user input char by char and prints `*` in it's place:

   ```
   #import sys (if option 1. is used)
   import getch

   def get_password():
       p = ''
       typed = ''

       while True:
           typed = getch.getch()

           if typed == '\n':
               print(typed)
               break

           p += typed

           # Choose one of the following solutions:

           # 1. General way. Needs import sys
           sys.stdout.write('*')
           sys.stdout.flush()

           # 2. Python 3 way:
           print('*', end='', flush=True)

      return p
   ```

Good luck :)

---

**EDIT:** For @timgeb 's comment about security:

From [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/getpass.html) documentation:

> On Unix, the prompt is written to the file-like object stream using the replace error handler if needed. 
> stream defaults to the controlling terminal (`/dev/tty`) or if that is unavailable to `sys.stderr` (this argument is ignored on Windows).

So it behaves quite similarly with the function above, except that mine has no fallback option...

Comment: Can anybody judge the safety of this compared to using the `getpass` module?

Comment: I can't seem to install the getch module on Windows. What should I do?

Comment: In windows install `msvcrt` and use it as `msvcrt.getch()`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    get_password()
  File "C:\Users\Default\Desktop\kjhgh.py", line 15, in get_password
    p += typed
TypeError: must be str, not bytes`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689365/python-3-typeerror-must-be-str-not-bytes-with-sys-stdout-write?answertab=votes#tab-top also since you are using Python 3, you can use the `print()` option instead!

Answer (score 1):

This one should do it:

```
import msvcrt
import sys

print('Enter your password: ')
password = ''
while True:
    pressedKey = msvcrt.getch()
    if pressedKey == '\r':    
       break
    else:
        password = password+pressedKey
        sys.stdout.write('*')

print('\n' + password)
```

It is `MS VC++` - Microsoft Visual C++ that works for windows. `getpass` uses this module, according to [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html)

Answer (score 0):

Really stop re-inventing the wheel.  DO NOT include something like this in your program, but have it use a password helper program.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67327327/701532

Of course if you write a GREAT password helper for inputing stars in python, like I did many years ago in shell... Go for it!