# inkex.py TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Tags: python, inkscape

I am trying to fix a problem in a function inside the inkex.py distributed with Inkscape. The function is

```
        def output(self):
        """Serialize document into XML on stdout"""
        original = etree.tostring(self.original_document)        
        result = etree.tostring(self.document)        
        if original != result:
            self.document.write(sys.stdout)
```

Error message is "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes". I think this is a problem in encoding as discussed in [Python 3 TypeError: must be str, not bytes with sys.stdout.write()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689365/python-3-typeerror-must-be-str-not-bytes-with-sys-stdout-write), but I don't understand how the input is passing here as I cannot see any input to the `sys.stdout` in `self.document.write(sys.stdout)`. The original source may be written for Python 2, but I have Python 3 in my system.

This is used to split text in inkscape program, and the complete error message is below:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "split.py", line 218, in <module>
    b.affect()
    File "C:\Program Files\Inkscape\share\extensions\inkex.py", line 285, in affect
    self.output()
    File "C:\Program Files\Inkscape\share\extensions\inkex.py", line 272, in output
    self.document.write(sys.stdout)
    File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 2057, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.write
    File "src\lxml\serializer.pxi", line 758, in lxml.etree._tofilelike
    File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 318, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored
    File "src\lxml\serializer.pxi", line 682, in lxml.etree._FilelikeWriter.write
    TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: Either use a Python2 system to run your Py2 code (not recommended as Python 2 hit EOL earlier this year), so consider upgrading to Python3. Or, decode the `sys.stdout` to off type `str` and not `bytes` as that is what python system is interpreting it as. Tip: Check the type of your data.

Comment: Updating could work, too... What's your Inkscape version? Have you checked if this is already fixed for Inkscape extensions in the official repository? (most probably, it is)

Answer (score 1):

I am using Inkscape version 0.92, and I didn't know about releases after this but 1.0 is released very recently.

However, I fixed the problem by changing the following line

```
if original != result:
            self.document.write(sys.stdout)
```

to

```
if original != result:
            self.document.write(sys.stdout.buffer)
```

Comment: This one fixed me too!