# Listing Gmail messages in one request?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

The Gmail search API has a [bug](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4608) that makes listing/searching email messages useless. In short, the http request returns a message ID and a snippet. No other fields like sender, date or subject.

Is there any other way/API to list/search Gmail messages/threads in one http request?

I can't use Google's libraries, I need a clean rest/http solution.

Comment: Not a bug. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445865/gmail-api-where-to-find-body-of-email-depending-of-mimetype/37463491#37463491) might give some clues.

Comment: @Tholle I must be missing something, I don't see any relevance. FYI, the API does not return the payload.

Comment: I stand corrected, I misunderstood. I apologize. You cannot get all relevant information in one request: You need to list message IDs as you stated, and then get each message separately. You can do it in 2 requests by making use of [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch).