# How to get content['payload']['body']['data'] first mail by gmail api

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail-api

I'm trying to get mail body by gmail api.

```
message = self.service.users().messages().get(userId=user, id=i,format='full').execute()
```

When I put my last email Id. Always I can't find contents in  `content['payload']['body']['data']`

It's shows like this.

```
"body": {
    "size": 0
}
```

Of course it has message body.

I can get sumally by `content['snippet']` ,but I can't get the message body body.

If you have any idea about this, please help me.

Comment: Could you provide the logs?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is what you want, how about ``res = [e['body']['size'] for e in message['payload']['parts']]`` or ``res = [e['body']['data'] for e in message['payload']['parts']]``? ``message`` is from your snippet.

Comment: The part you are looking for is located in different locations depending on what type of message it is. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445865/gmail-api-where-to-find-body-of-email-depending-of-mimetype/37463491#37463491) might give some inspiration.

Answer (score 6):

I solved my problem by this method. Thank you Tanaike!

```
def data_encoder(text):
    if len(text)>0:
        message = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(text)
        message = str(message, 'utf-8')
        message = email.message_from_string(message)
    return message


def readMessage(content)->str:
    message = None
    if "data" in content['payload']['body']:
        message = content['payload']['body']['data']
        message = data_encoder(message)
    elif "data" in content['payload']['parts'][0]['body']:
        message = content['payload']['parts'][0]['body']['data']
        message = data_encoder(message)
    else:
        print("body has no data.")
    return message
```

Comment: @Nori - My apologies for mistakenly downvoting your answer when I actually meant to upvote it. So I edited it by removing the commented line. I will upvote the same once it gets peer reviewed.