# Parsing an email message body

Tags: python, email, parsing, gmail-api

I'm using the gmail API to parse through my gmail message body. It works other than when the body is in an html. Does anyone know how I can just extract the text within the email? If not, how I can just ignore emails with html?

Eventually I want to implement this for personal/professional emails in which there likely won't be html in it.

```
def message_converter(message_id):
        message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message_id,format='raw').execute()
        msg_str = str(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('ASCII')),'UTF-8')
        mime_msg = email.message_from_string(msg_str)
        if mime_msg.is_multipart():
            for payload in mime_msg.get_payload():
                # if payload.is_multipart(): ...
                print (payload.get_payload())
        else:
            print (mime_msg.get_payload())
```

Comment: You might have run into the issue discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445865/gmail-api-where-to-find-body-of-email-depending-of-mimetype/37463491#37463491).

Answer (score 0):

[html2text](https://github.com/aaronsw/html2text) does a pretty good job - it converts HTML into ASCII text.

You may need to do additional parsing/formatting after the fact, however.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if this can help you but Gmail Api have the same syntax so in C# you can find the text message in 3 places (it depends on the mail server) so :

```
msg.Payload.Parts[1].Body.Data;  // here you can find text message without HTML tag

msg.Payload.Parts[0].Body.Data; // here you can find text message with HTML tag

msg.Payload.Body.Data; // and here you dont have a choice you have the HTMl tag
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer may help you do what you are heading to. I understand that you wanna get certain texts out of the body of the email. You may use regular expressions to do that. I made a video explaining how to get data out of Gmail email body but using Google App Script (JavaScript):

https://youtu.be/nI1OH3pAz6s?t=8

You download the code from GitHub link:

https://gist.github.com/MoayadAbuRmilah/5835369fdebbecf980029f7339e4d769