# GMail API does not deliver attachment

Tags: gmail-api

I'm getting a weird behaviour from gmail that I can't figure:
I'm using the GMail API as described and I can send and receive messages.
The Problem is, when I create a multipart message with a file attachment, that file is stripped from the message after sending. I.e. the attachment shows up fine in the Sent folder, but the receiver gets the message without attachment. I also checked the original message on both sides and on the sent message I have all 3 parts (1 text 2 html 3 png) and on the receiving side I only have parts 1 and 2.
Fun twist: when I forward the message from my Sent folder to the same recipient, the attachment is sent.

The code-snippet for the message creation is the following:

```py
# processing incoming email
        for part in email_msg.walk():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                continue
            if 'text/plain' in part.get_content_type():
                payload += part.get_payload(decode=True)
            elif 'text/html' in part.get_content_type():
                html_payload += part.get_payload(decode=True)
            elif part.get('Content-Disposition') is not None and part.get_filename() != 'smime.p7s':
                attachments.append(
                    {'data_stream': part.get_payload(decode=True),
                     'filename': part.get_filename(),
                     'content_type': part.get_content_type()
                     }
                )
#part creating the message
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = 'my_gsuite_address'
    msg['To'] = user_mail
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body_msg_plain, 'plain', "utf-8"))
    if html_message != '':
        body_msg_html = ISSUE_UPDATED_MESSAGE_HTML.format(
            message=html_message,
            footer=MM_FOOTER_PLAIN
        )
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body_msg_html, 'html', "utf-8"))
    for attachment in attachments:
        main_type, sub_type = attachment['content_type'].split('/')
        if main_type == 'text':
            mime_class = MIMEText
        elif main_type == 'image':
            mime_class = MIMEImage
        elif main_type == 'audio':
            mime_class = MIMEAudio
        else:
            mime_class = MIMEBase
        attachment_part = mime_class(attachment['data_stream'], _subtype=sub_type)
        attachment_part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=attachment["filename"])
        msg.attach(attachment_part)
#part sending the message
self.service.users().messages().send(
            userId=self.account,
            body={'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(msg.as_bytes()).decode('utf-8')}
        ).execute()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you please share the code related to `attachments`? Also, have you noticed whether this behaviour happens only with certain attachments?

Comment: I just added the attachment part. So far I tested png, svg and pdf, none of which work...

Comment: Have you tried setting the MIME to `multipart/mixed`? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37462718).

Comment: Thanks @Iamblichus, that seems to solved my issue!