# Setting up Gmail Push Notification for a specific email having attachments

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub, google-workspace

I am trying to set up Gmail Push Notification to create a watch request for any new email received in the INBOX. So far, this is fine. However, I am trying to create a watch request as described here :

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#getting_gmail_mailbox_updates

I would like to set up a watch request for any email received from a specific email(info@abc.com) address having a subject line "[Important]" and having a PDF attachment.

Any idea if such a watch request can be set up?

Currently, I am reading all the emails from INBOX using `imaplib` received in the last 24 hours and manually search for emails having the subject line and attachment. However, I believe, this solution is not ideal.

Comment: `watch` requests cannot be customized at this level, but you could (1) get Push Notifications for all INBOX, (2) call `history.list` to get the details of the changes and (3) use the reponse body to `history.list` to filter the messages to only the ones coming from a certain email & having certain subject & having PDF attachment. Do you think that would be a good solution for you? If that's the case, I'd post an answer with more details on the corresponding workflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Please elaborate, I will explore this.

Answer (score 4):

#### Issue:

The only filter you can apply to Gmail Push Notifications is which label/s to retrieve notifications from, as can be seen [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch#request-body). Because of this, the filtering of messages depending on (1) who sent the message, (2) the email subject and (3) whether the email has a certain PDF attachment cannot be done at this stage, but after receiving the notifications. Luckily, though, there is no need to look for these messages manually, you can code your application to do that for you.

#### Workflow:

**- Step #1. Set notifications for all INBOX and retrieve startHistoryId**: As was said before, you have to receive notifications for all INBOX, since there is no more specific filter available. A call to [Users: watch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch), providing `INBOX` in the `labelIds` field and the [topic you created](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#create_a_topic) in `topicName`, will effectively configure the notifications. The response to `watch` has [this shape](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#watch_response):

```
{
  historyId: 1234567890
  expiration: 1431990098200
}
```

Where `historyId` refers to the mailbox’s current state. Let’s store it somewhere, and call it `startHistoryId`.

**- Step #2. Get INBOX changes**: After completing step 1, whenever there is a change in your `INBOX`, your application will receive a notification message describing the change. Whenever a notification is received, you want to get information about the specific changes made to the `INBOX`, and to achieve that, you should call [history.list()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list).

That is to say, your application should call `history.list()` every time a notification is received. Now, you want to get changes since last time, and that’s why you should provide the `historyId` retrieved in step 1 as the parameter `startHistoryId`. If you want to only retrieve new messages (and not deletions, or label edition/removal), you can set `historyTypes` to `messageAdded`. The request could be like this:

```
{
  userId: “your-email-address”,
  historyTypes: “messageAdded”,
  startHistoryId: “your-start-history-id”
}
```

As a response, you’ll get something like this:

```
{
  "history": [
    {
      "id": unsigned long,
      "messages": [
        users.messages Resource
      ],
      "messagesAdded": [
        {
          "message": users.messages Resource
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "historyId": unsigned long
}
```

Here, you should retrieve **historyId**, **which will be used as `startHistoryId` the next time `history.list()` is called**, and **messagesAdded**, which contains the `IDs` of the new messages you want to look for (only `ID` and `threadId` seem to be populated).

**- Step 3. Filtering messages**: Now you have the list of message `IDs` that have changed since last time (`messagesAdded`), and you want to know which of them match your criteria. To know that, you’ll have to iterate through all `IDs` in `messagesAdded` and call [Users.messages: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) for each `ID`. This will return the corresponding [message resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages). For each message, you’ll have to check whether the criteria are met:

- **Sender email**: inside the resource, access the `headers` (message[“payload”][“headers”]), and loop through them, looking for the one whose `name` is `From`. You have to check whether the corresponding `value` is the email you’re looking for.
- **Subject**: as in step (a), access the `headers` and look for the header whose `name` is `Subject`. The corresponding `value` is the email subject. Check whether it starts with `[Important]`.
- **Attachment**: you’ll have to look for the email attachments in `message[“payload”][“parts”]`. The process is a bit more complicated, but see, for example, [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25832631).

#### Reference:

[Gmail API: Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)

Comment: But I think company like google should have provided basic filtering of email logic through this watch request based on subject,email,date time.