# Download Attachment from gmail api using Python

Tags: python, api, rest, gmail-api

I am trying to download the attachment from gmail using the python and I am not able to fetch the attachment id from my mail. Please find my code below

```
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


def get_gmail_service():
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

        try:
            # Call the Gmail API
            service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
            return service

        except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
            print(f'An error occurred: {error}')

def get_email_list():
    service = get_gmail_service()
    results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',q='from:abc@gmail.com is:read').execute()
    # print(results.get('messages',[])[0].get('id',[]))
    return results.get('messages', [])[0].get('id', [])
    # return results.get('messages',[])

def get_email_content(message_id):
    service = get_gmail_service()
    attach = service.users().messages().get(userId='me',id =message_id).execute()
    attach_id = attach.get('payloads',[]).get('parts',[]).get('body',[])
    data = service.users().messages().get(userId='me',id = message_id).execute()
    return attach_id

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # get_email_list()
    print(get_email_content(get_email_list()))
```

Please correct my code so that I can download the attachment using the gmail api.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download attachments from Gmail using Gmail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832631/download-attachments-from-gmail-using-gmail-api)

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues with this code.

1. `results.get()` method either returns a [Message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#resource:-message) or [MessagePart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#messagepart) Object. So you only need to use the `get()` method once to get the complete object and then you can target the specific part of the object you want.

   For Example. `results.get('messages', [])[0]['id']`
2. A payload for an email can be multipart (which means that "parts" will be an array of `MessagePart` objects). So we need to iterate over to get a "message part" that has a file. In this case, we can check if the MessagePart object has a filename.

```
    parts = attach.get('payload',[])['parts']
    
    for i in parts:
        if( i['filename'] ):
            return i['body']['attachmentId']
```

So After taking care of these two issues, this is the new code:

```
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


def get_gmail_service():
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

        try:
            # Call the Gmail API
            service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
            return service

        except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
            print(f'An error occurred: {error}')

def get_email_list():
    service = get_gmail_service()
    results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',q='from:abc@gmail.com is:read').execute()
    # print(results.get('messages',[])[0]['id'] )
    return results.get('messages', [])[0]['id']
    # return results.get('messages',[])

def get_email_content(message_id):
    print(message_id)
    service = get_gmail_service()
    data = service.users().messages().get(userId='me',id = message_id).execute()

    attach = service.users().messages().get(userId='me',id =message_id).execute()
    parts = attach.get('payload',[])['parts']
    
    for i in parts:
        if( i['filename'] ):
            return i['body']['attachmentId'] 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # get_email_list()
    print(get_email_content(get_email_list()))
```

I hope this answers your question!