# Python Write to Text File Skip Bad Lines

Tags: python, html, text, io

RESOLVED: Problem had to do with Python version, refer to stackoverflow.com/a/5513856/2540382

I am fiddling with `htm -> txt` file conversion and am having a little trouble. My project is essentially to convert the `messages.htm` file I downloaded of my Facebook chat history into a `messages.txt` file with all the `<>` brackets removed and formatting preserved.

The file `messages.htm` is parsed into variable `text`.

I then run:

```
target = open('output.txt', 'w')
target.write(text)
target.close
```

This seems to work except when I hit an invalid character. As seen in the error below. Is there a way to either:

1. Skip the line with the invalid character while writing?
2. Figure out where the invalid characters are and remove the corresponding character or line?

The desired outcome is to avoid having strange characters all together if possible.

```
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U000fe333' in position 37524: character
maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Tip(but not the problem): `file.close` is a function so you have to use `target.close()` to call it.

Comment: Can you give an example of invalid characters?

Comment: @flamenco, they give the example ['\U000fe333'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fe333/index.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
target = open('output.txt', 'wb')
target.write(text.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
target.close()
```

For the "errors" argument to .encode(..), 'ignore' will strip out those characters, and 'replace' will replace them with '?'.

To test this, I replaced the write line with

```
target.write(u"foo\U000fe333bar".encode("ascii", "ignore"))
```

and confirmed that output.txt contained only "foobar".

**UPDATE:** I edited the `open(.., 'w')` to `open(.., 'wb')` to make sure this would work in Python 3 as well.

Comment: Hmm I get this error:   File "html2text.py", line 693, in wrapwrite
    target.write(text.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: What type is "text"? I tested it with a string and Python 2.7.10.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I added print(type(text)) to the code. Cmd is telling me that the type is string. C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\workspace>python html2text.py part1.htm
<class 'str'>

Comment: It appears to be a change between Python 2 and Python 3. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5513856/2540382

Comment: not woork for  me f.write(towrite.encode("ascii", "ignore"))

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes